# Creating a grid view of products in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

very new to PHP to please bear with.

As you can see from my snippet of code I am simply displaying product information one line under each other then repeating the loop using while. This then obviously displays my relevant data in just one column, one under each other.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

    echo "<img src=\"images/album1.jpg\"/><br>"; //this will eventually show the product image
    echo "<a href=\"product.php?id=$row[0]\">$row[1] </a><br>"; //this shows the product name
    echo "<strong>&pound$row[2]</strong><br>"; //this shows the product price

            }
```

How would I go about creating a grid view, for example using columns to display my data? I presume it would be some kind of loop to be added and maybe using tables to display my data?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can dot this by creating div and float that div to left this will create grid view

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    echo "<div class='container'>";
    echo "<img src=\"images/album1.jpg\"/><br>"; //this will eventually show the product image
    echo "<a href=\"product.php?id=$row[0]\">$row[1] </a><br>"; //this shows the product name
    echo "<strong>&pound$row[2]</strong><br>"; //this shows the product price
    echo "</div>";
    }
```

and css

```
.container{
  float:left;
}
```

you can 
also set the max height and width of div

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you my friend.